# Regex & Sublime Text 2

Tags: regex

I recently got Sublime text and I was wondering how I could do the following thing.
I have a list full of random keywords from Google Keywords.
Now I wanna remove a part which comes with the download.
Every line looks like this:
"Conceptcampagne            EUR     Ropa Interior               tiendas de ropa interior"
I wanna remove this part: "Conceptcampagne          EUR     Ropa Interior               "
But, the "ropa interior" part is always different.
I want to make this easier by regex. Yet I have no clue.

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

regex = Conceptcampagne EUR .* (tiendas de ropa interior)
Replace with \1

You may have to add a "?" after the .*

Comment: Thank you very much Jody! Much appreciated! Like litterally, thank you. Saves me so much work!